# Creating a snapshot database to another SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm trying to save the values of several columns of one table to another table on a different server. I am using SQL Server. I would like to do this without running external programs that query from this database and insert the results into the new database. Is there any way to do this from within the SQL Server Management Studio?

This is a recurring event that occurs every hour. I have tried scheduling maintenance tasks that execute custom T-SQL scripts but I'm having trouble getting the connection to the remote server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you can set up the remote server as a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) you should be able to configure the [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) to execute jobs that contain queries that access tables on both the local and linked server. Remember that you might have to configure the access rights for the account used to run SQL Server Agent so that it has permissions to read/write tables on both servers.

This practice might not be without issues though as [this article](http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/linked-servers-and-distributed-queries/) discusses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 4 part name like;

```
INSERT [InstanceName].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]
SELECT * FROM [SourceInstanceName].[SourceDatabaseName].[SourceSchemaName].[SourceTableName]
```

But first you will have to set the remote server as a linked server as so;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx